# Variable in dataframe in ddmmyyyy, to be split as Mon and Yr as separate columns, when date between 1-15, then take current month, else next month

Tags: r, date

Col1 has to be split as two. One with month(Col2) and other with year(Col3).
When the date is less than or equal to 15, then current month has to be populated. If the date is more than 15th, then next month has to be populated in Col2. If date is more than 15th with month is Dec, then the month as well year has to be updated and populated.

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
13-02-2017  Feb 2017
22-01-2017  Feb 2017
27-12-2017  Jan 2018
```

Comment: could you show your attempt please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)
dates <- c("13-02-2017", "22-01-2017", "27-12-2017")

myDateFun <- function(x){
    x <- as.Date(x, format='%d-%m-%Y')
    if (day(x) >= 15){
     dd <- x+17 
    }
    else {dd <- x}

    return(c(month(dd), year(dd)))
}

t(sapply(dates, FUN=myDateFun, simplify='matrix'))
```

Returns

```
           [,1] [,2]
13-02-2017    2 2017
22-01-2017    2 2017
27-12-2017    1 2018
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to Date class giving `d` and then convert that to yearmon `ym` adding 1/12 (which increments the month and also the year if need be) if the day > 15. In the last line extract the month and year back out.

```
library(zoo)   

d <- as.Date(DF$Col1, "%d-%m-%Y")
ym <- as.yearmon(d) + (as.POSIXlt(d)$mday > 15) / 12
transform(DF, Col2 = format(ym, "%b"), Col3 = as.integer(ym))
```

giving:

```
        Col1 Col2 Col3
1 13-02-2017  Feb 2017
2 22-01-2017  Feb 2017
3 27-12-2017  Jan 2018
```

### Note

We used this test input

```
DF <- data.frame(Col1 = c("13-02-2017", "22-01-2017", "27-12-2017"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lubridate` and `dplyr`, you can do

```
df$Col1 <- dmy(df$Col1)
df %>% 
  mutate(
    Col2 = ifelse(day(Col1) < 15, month.abb[month(Col1)], month.abb[(month(Col1)+1) %% 12]), 
    Col3 = ifelse(day(Col1) > 15 & month(Col1) == 12 , year(Col1)+1, year(Col1)))

#         Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1 2017-02-13  Feb 2017
# 2 2017-01-22  Feb 2017
# 3 2017-12-27  Jan 2018
```

---

### Data

```
tt <-'Col1
13-02-2017
22-01-2017
27-12-2017'

df <- read.table(text = tt, header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(col1 = dmy(col1)) %>%
  mutate(temp = as.Date(ifelse(day(col1)<=15, col1, col1 %m+% months(1)), origin='1970-01-01'),
         col2 = format(temp, "%b"),
         col3 = year(temp)) %>%
  select(-temp)
```

**Output is:**

```
        col1 col2 col3
1 2017-02-13  Feb 2017
2 2017-01-22  Feb 2017
3 2017-12-27  Jan 2018
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("13-02-2017", 
"22-01-2017", "27-12-2017"), class = "factor")), .Names = "col1", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```